# Executing Mono streams that no one subscribes to in Spring Web flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have a spring Webflux application. There are two important parts to this application:

1. A job is scheduled to run at a fixed interval.
2. The job fetches the data from DB and stores the data in Redis.

```java
void run() {
  redisAdapter.getTtl()
    .doOnError(RefreshExternalCache::logError)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
        log.debug(">> RefreshExternalCache > refreshExternalCacheIfNeeded => Remaining TTL could not be retrieved. Cache does not exist. " +
                "Trying to create the cache.");
        return Mono.just(Duration.ofSeconds(0));
    }))
    .subscribe(remainingTtl -> {
        log.debug(">> RefreshExternalCache > refreshExternalCacheIfNeeded => original ttl for the cache: {} | ttl for cache in seconds = {} | ttl for cache in minutes = {}",
                remainingTtl, remainingTtl.getSeconds(), remainingTtl.toMinutes());

        if (isExternalCacheRefreshNeeded(remainingTtl, offerServiceProperties.getExternalCacheExpiration(), offerServiceProperties.getExternalCacheRefreshPeriod())) {
            log.debug(">> RefreshExternalCache > refreshExternalCacheIfNeeded => external cache is up-to-date, skipping refresh");
        } else {
            log.debug(">> RefreshExternalCache > refreshExternalCacheIfNeeded => external cache is outdated, updating the external cache");
            offerService.refreshExternalCache();
        }
    });
}
```

This basically calls another method called `refreshExternalCache()`, the implementation below:

```java
public void refreshExternalCache() {
    fetchOffersFromSource()
        .doOnNext(offerData -> {
            log.debug(LOG_REFRESH_CACHE + "Updating local offer cache with data from source");
            localCache.put(OFFER_DATA_KEY, offerData);
            storeOffersInExternalCache(offerData, offerServiceProperties.getExternalCacheExpiration());
        })
        .doOnSuccess(offerData -> meterRegistry.counter(METRIC_EXTERNAL_CACHE_REFRESH_COUNTER, TAG_OUTCOME, SUCCESS).increment())
        .doOnError(sourceThrowable -> {
            log.debug(LOG_REFRESH_CACHE + "Error while refreshing external cache {}", sourceThrowable.getMessage());
            meterRegistry.counter(METRIC_EXTERNAL_CACHE_REFRESH_COUNTER, TAG_OUTCOME, FAILURE).increment();
        }).subscribe();
}
```

Also, in the above method, you can see a call to `storeOffersInExternalCache`

```java
public void storeOffersInExternalCache(OfferData offerData, Duration ttl) {
    log.info(LOG_STORING_OFFER_DATA + "Storing the offer data in external cache...");
    redisAdapter.storeOffers(offerData, ttl);
}
```

```java
public void storeOffers(OfferData offerData, Duration ttl) {
    Mono.fromRunnable(() -> redisClient.storeSerializedOffers(serializeFromDomain(offerData), ttl)
        .doOnNext(status -> {
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(status)) {
                log.info(LOG_STORE_OFFERS + "Data stored in redis.");
                meterRegistry.counter(METRIC_REDIS_STORE_OFFERS, TAG_OUTCOME, SUCCESS).increment();
            } else {
                log.error(LOG_STORE_OFFERS + "Unable to store data in redis.");
                meterRegistry.counter(METRIC_REDIS_STORE_OFFERS, TAG_OUTCOME, FAILURE).increment();
            }
        }).retryWhen(Retry.backoff(redisRetryProperties.getMaxAttempts(), redisRetryProperties.getWaitDuration()).jitter(redisRetryProperties.getBackoffJitter()))
        .doOnError(throwable -> {
            meterRegistry.counter(METRIC_REDIS_STORE_OFFERS, TAG_OUTCOME, FAILURE).increment();
            log.error(LOG_STORE_OFFERS + "Unable to store data in redis. Error: [{}]", throwable.getMessage());
        })).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

**Redis Client**

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class RedisClient {
    private final ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplate;
    private final ReactiveValueOperations<String, String> reactiveValueOps;

    public RedisClient(@Qualifier("reactiveRedisTemplate") ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplate) {
        this.reactiveRedisTemplate = reactiveRedisTemplate;
        this.reactiveValueOps = reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForValue();
    }

    Mono<Optional<String>> fetchSerializedOffers() {
        return reactiveValueOps.get(OFFER_DATA_KEY).map(Optional::ofNullable);
    }

    Mono<Boolean> storeSerializedOffers(String serializedOffers, Duration ttl) {
        return reactiveValueOps.set(OFFER_DATA_KEY, serializedOffers, ttl);
    }

    Mono<Duration> getTtl() {
        return reactiveRedisTemplate.getExpire(OFFER_DATA_KEY);
    }
}
```

Now my concerns are:

1. If I do not call the `subscribe` method on these Mono streams, these methods are not even executed. This is fair as they won't execute until someone subscribes to them.
2. As I understand it correctly, `subscribe` is a blocking call. This defeats the whole purpose of Reactive programming. Isn't it?
3. I looked for several ways to make this work, one of them has been shown above. I tried calling one of the methods in `Mono.fromRunnable` but this also is not a very good approach. (read it on another thread in StackOverflow).

So, is the approach that I am taking above not correct? How do we execute the Mono streams that no one subscribes to?

Comment: If the DB and Redis client you use are reactive then subscribe won't be blocking. Otherwise you should combine sunscribeOn with subscribe to make it async and don't put any heavy logic into subscribe. Anyway, the best approach is to use reactive clients.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi I basically do not have any DB clients here. What I am doing is - first fetching the data from Redis. If no data is there in Redis, then I make an API call (using WebClient) and fetch the data from the source (external API). Still, will subscribe() be a blocking call?

Comment: WebClient is reactive, that is good. Is the Redis client you use reactive?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Yes. I am using below two for Redis operations:
`private final ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplate;
private final ReactiveValueOperations<String, String> reactiveValueOps;`
I have included the Redis Client code in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your concern number 2 (which seems to be the only real doubt in your question). Not really. `block()` (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--) is the one that subscribes to a `Mono` or `Flux` and waits indefinitely until a next signal is received. On the other hand `subscribe()` (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe--) subscribes to a `Mono` or `Flux` but it doesn't block and instead reacts when an element is emitted.

Comment: Thank you, @João Dias. This solves my confusion. I just was not sure whether subscribe() waits for the call to complete or not.